# problem 11248 from AMM

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Good evening everyone , please I need help on this difficult problem

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$ with the property that $\int_{0}^{1} x^{k}f(x)\,dx=1$ for all $k \in \{0,..,n-1\}$ . Prove that $\int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^2\,dx\geq n^2$

Comment: Reference, that you should have given : **Pál Péter Dályay, Jaime Vinuesa:
A Romanian Olympiad Problem Generalized: 11248. The American Mathematical Monthly 115(4): 368-369 (2008)**. It means that an answer has been given, say a year or more later. Why didn't you try to find it ?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a straightforward application for [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality), althought there's undoubtedly a more elegant way the authors had in mind. We can use the fact that we have an orthogonal series of polynomials on $L^2(-1,1)$, the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality) satisfying
$$\int_{-1}^{1} P_m(x) P_n(x)\,dx = {2 \over {2n + 1}} \delta_{mn}.$$
For $L^2(0,1)$, we can find an orthonormal basis of
$$p_n(x) = \sqrt{2n+1} P_n(2x-1)$$
satisfying
$$\int_{0}^{1} p_m(x) p_n(x)\,dx = \delta_{mn}.$$

Now Bessel's inequality for $L^2(0,1)$ says that
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx \ge \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left| \int_0^1 p_k(x) f(x) dx \right|^2.$$
Writing $p_k(x)$ as a polynomial, we note that the highest power is always $k$:
$$p_k(x) = \sum_{l=0}^k \alpha_{k,l} x^l,$$
and thus
$$\int_0^1 p_k(x) f(x) dx = \sum_{l=0}^k \alpha_{k,l} \underbrace{\int_0^1 x^l f(x) dx}_{=1} = p_k(1) = \sqrt{2k+1}$$
for all $k$ up to $n-1$ by the assumption and using properties of $P_k(x)$.

Finally,
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx \ge \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{2n+1}^2 = n^2.$$

Comment: "There's undoubtedly a more elegant way the authors had in mind" - The solution [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00029890.2008.11920539) uses a similar method